# JS Duplicate a div in a random position

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing a web page in which a **user when clicking on a button a certain div must be duplicated in a random position**. I'm having trouble duplicating the div, this is the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'appendChild')

This is the JavaScript code:

```
  var divClone = gifRoll.cloneNode(true);
  divClone.style.top = Math.random() * (1000) + 'px';
  divClone.style.bottom = Math.random() * (1000) + 'px';
  divClone.style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('contenitore').appendChild(divClone);
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Error says, that ```document.getElementById('contenitore')``` is null.

Please chceck, if element with id contenitore exists.

Comment: Reading the error, `document.getElementById('contenitore')` is null, are you sure to get element with this id in your dom?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your HTML, so I am unsure what might have been missing there.

But in the javascript, you may have been missing the creation of the `gifRoll` variable.  The rest of your code works, assuming all the HTML is present. See my demo below.

```js
  var gifRoll = document.getElementById('gifRoll');
  var btnDupe = document.querySelector('button');
  
 btnDupe.addEventListener('click', () => {
   doTheThing();
 });
  
function doTheThing(){
  var divClone = gifRoll.cloneNode(true);
  divClone.id = 'a' + Math.random() * (100);
  divClone.classList.add('newdiv');
  divClone.style.top = Math.random() * (1000) + 'px';
  divClone.style.bottom = Math.random() * (1000) + 'px';
  divClone.style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('contenitore').appendChild(divClone);
}
```

```css
#contenitore{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:110px;
  background:wheat;
}

#gifRoll{
  background:green;
}
.dupe{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.newdiv{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenitore"></div>
<div id="gifRoll" class="dupe"></div>
<button>Dupe It</button>
```